# pandas : plot stacked barchart for row values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have below data frame and I wanted to plot stacked bar chart for 'closed'/'open' state.

```
             state  requests
created                          
2016-09-28    OPEN              1
2017-02-03    OPEN              1 
2017-06-15  CLOSED              1
2017-06-15    OPEN              1
2017-06-16  CLOSED              2
2017-08-23    OPEN              1
2017-10-25    OPEN              1
2018-01-19    OPEN              1
2018-03-01    OPEN              1
2018-03-05    OPEN              1
2018-06-12    OPEN              1
2018-06-15    OPEN              1
```

I have tried following(df_temp is dataframe of above data)

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylabel('Requests')
df_closed = df_temp[df_temp['state'] == 'CLOSED']
df_open = df_temp[df_temp['state'] == 'OPEN']

b = ax.bar(x = df_open.index.get_level_values(0), height = df_open['requests'])
a = ax.bar(x = df_closed.index.get_level_values(0), height = df_closed['requests'],bottom = df_open['requests'])
```

but it is giving me error as

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Comment: You can take a look here: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html. That is, first you should plot one of the two (e.g. `ax.bar(df_closed.index, df_closed.requests)`), then the other by specifying it should start above (e.g. `ax.bar(df_open.index, df_open.requests, bottom=df_closed.requests)`. EDIT: you should first make sure that they have the same indices, e.g. `df_closed.reindex(...).fillna(0)`, where "..." is the union of the two set of indices.

Comment: @MarcoSpinaci, thank you for your reply, it works but what if 'state' column values are unknown. Say there is 10 different states, so is there any way we can do it by loop or something else?

Comment: Yes I'd probably do a for loop, something like `for s in df.state.unique()`, and at each step update a "bottom" series that says how much we've added so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention pandas pivot function - [you can transform your dataset with it](http://nikgrozev.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/) in one line before you stack the bar chart:

```
df_temp.pivot(columns = "state", values = "requests").plot(kind = "bar", stacked = True)
```

Now we can additionally beautify the graph - label the y-axis, rotate the x-tick labels:

```
plt.ylabel("Requests")
plt.xticks(rotation = 45, ha = "right")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank You, Mr. T. 
It worked very well, I found pivot table syntax somewhat confusing, this one helped me.

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest way to achieve the scope, much better than my loop solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting a proper answer here since it's probably easier than keeping commenting. This also includes the further case (asked in the comment) where there might be an arbitrary, unknown set of values in `state`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = df_temp.index.unique()
cumsum = pd.Series(0, index=index)
for s in df.state.unique():
    new_vals = df_temp.loc[df.state == s, 'requests'].reindex(index).fillna(0)
    ax.bar(index, new_vals, bottom = cumsum)
    cumsum += new_vals
ax.set_ylabel('Requests')
```

This should take care of everything. Within each ax, I'd probably also put a `label=s` and add an `ax.legend()` in the end to map each resulting color to one status.

Comment: Thank you, Marco. It works with any number of states. 
just a small mistake, it should be ax.bar(index, new_vals, bottom = cumsum) instead of ax.bar(index, new_vals, cumsum), other wise it will plot graph for the last one only.